# matrices self-adjoint with respect to some inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to give a nice characterization of matrices $A \in R^{n \times n}$ which are self-adjoint with respect to *some* inner product?

These matrices include all symmetric matrices (of course) and some nonsymmetric ones: for example, the transition matrix of any (irreducible) reversible Markov chain will have this property.

Naturally, all such matrices must have real eigenvalues, though I do not expect that this is a sufficient condition (is it?).

About the only observation I have is that since any inner product
can be represented as $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T M y$ for some positive definite matrix $M$, we are looking for matrices $A$ which satisfy $A^T M = M A$ or $M^{-1} A^T M = A$. In other words, we are looking for real matrices similar to their transpose with a positive definite similarity matrix.

Comment: Dear angela, how do we know that it has real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to having real eigenvalues, the matrix will have to be diagonalizable, i.e., there have to be enough eigenvectors to span $R^n$.  Once these conditions are satisfied, you can take a basis consisting of $n$ eigenvectors and define an inner product by declaring these basis vectors to be orthonormal.  That inner product will make your matrix self-adjoint, because there's an orthonormal basis with respect to which the matrix is diagonal with real entries on the diagonal.

Comment: So, a subset of the set of normal matrices, then?

Comment: @J. Mandalgan: No, there are plenty of examples of a matrix diagonalizable over the reals which does not commute with its transpose, such as $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &amp; 1 \\\\ 0 &amp; 1\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Thanks Tracy for the explanation; somehow I had remembered mistakenly that "normal" is synonymous with "diagonalizable".

Comment: J. Mangaldan: Normal matrices are precisely those that can be diagonalised via a *unitary* transformation.


Comment: Tracy Hall: normal matrices are not those which commute with their transpose, but those which commute with their adjoint relative to the inner product.  If the inner product is the usual "dot" product, then this is indeed the transpose, but not necessarily otherwise.  Your 2x2 matrix is not just normal, but indeed symmetric, relative to the inner product $\begin{bmatrix}\hphantom{-}1 & -1 \cr -1 & \hphantom{-}0\end{bmatrix}$. 

Comment: José: So I did forget that crucial part of the definition of "normal", thanks for reminding. But I suppose "no" is still the answer to my first question?

Comment: J. Mangaldan: If by "normal" you mean that it commutes with the adjoint relative to some inner product, then this is true by definition.  If by "normal"  you mean that it commutes with the transpose, then as Tracy Hall pointed out, the answer is no.


Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan It has real eigenvalues because it is self-adjoint.

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan This should be in any textbook of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: Indefinite linear algebra and applications ---  Israel Gohberg,Peter Lancaster,L. Rodman, section 4.2.